# Невозможно привести COM-объект типа Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass к интерфейсному типу Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application

Tags: c#, ms-word, com, office-interop, interop

Пытаюсь запустить простейший код консольного приложения:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleAppTestWord
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            Document doc = app.Documents.Add(Visible:true);
            doc.Save();
            doc.Close();
            app.Quit();

        }
    }
}
```

На строке `Document doc = app.Documents.Add(Visible:true);` выдает ошибку:

> Невозможно привести COM-объект типа
>   "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass" к интерфейсному типу
>   "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application".

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: уточните, на какое именно действие у вас такая ошибка -- пробовал ваш код, у меня такая ошибка не воспроизводиться, только если от диалога сохранения отказаться ожидаемо кидает исключение, но оно другое.

Comment: навскидку, похоже на путаницу пространств имён при создании `Application`.

Comment: А офис установлен на ПК? Какой версии? Какую версию библиотеки Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word подключили?

Comment: Как вариант - поставьте `var` вместо `Document` и не мучайтесь.

Comment: Офис установлен - Office 365, все программы - и ворд, и эксель, вплоть до паблишера. Подключил ссылку Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library, потом прописал using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word - ошибок не выдало. Ошибка выпадает при компиляции.

Comment: Проблема не в коде, а на машине, с офисом. Попробуйте ему сделать восстановление, а также проверить, что программа использует точно ту версию офиса, которая установлена

Comment: У меня ваш код работает, только что проверил. Только я не "Подключил ссылку Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library" как вы, а установил nuget пакет `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

Comment: Нужно переустановить офис или сделать восстановление. [Подробно здесь.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d34c4f78-46f3-478e-9c44-95ea8461e46f/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-office-interop-word?forum=vsto)

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том какие версии установлены у вас на машине и что прописано в реестре ключей Windows.

1. Найди версию Office прописанную в реестре Windows

Для 64bit Office ищи тут:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\Interface[00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046]\TypeLib

Для 32bit Office ищи тут:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \Interface[00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046]\TypeLib

[image: Поиск ключа версии Office]

2. Найди ключ в этом каталоге

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ WOW6432Node \TypeLib[the TypeLib ID you just found].
[image: Поиск ключа 2]

3. Убедись что версии в обоих каталогах совпадают и в ключе №2 прописана только одна! версия.

Оригинал статьи тут: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d34c4f78-46f3-478e-9c44-95ea8461e46f/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-office-interop-word?forum=vsto

Comment: +++ спаситель, а уже хотел винду переустановить )